# How to make caret/Ibeam of a focused RichTextBox in C# blink indefinitely

Tags: c#, caret

The caret in my RichTextBox only blinks 5 or 6 times before it becomes a solid line that no longer flashes. I noticed this happens in some native windows programs like Wordpad so it's probably intended behavior. However, I noticed that some programs like Notepad++ and Visual Studio are able to make the caret blink indefinitely. I've looked around online but there doesn't seem to be any clear way to do this. Anyone know how to go about it?

Comment: Just in case anyone else ever wonders about this, I found out that this is the native behavior of the textbox control in WinForms. However, the textbox control in WPF applications will blink indefinitely.